# overloads in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Overloads” keyword in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173257/overloads-keyword-in-vb-net)

what exactly overloads signifies in vb.net coz even if  i am not writing the overloads in derived class function its working in the similar manner when i am writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Function overloading allows more than one function to be defined with the same name in the same class, as long as the arguments are different. Not to be confused with function overriding where functions have the same number, type of arguments its the implementations in the derived classes that differs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the overloads keyword in vb.net is completely optional, and is there only to support better readability of the code.

There is an all-or-nothing rule, however, so if you use it for one method, you have to use it for all overloading methods.