# Is the 'Overloads' keyword ever required in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, overloading

As the title says. From what I can see online the **Overloads** keyword is optional but is there ever a time when it is necessary? It even seems to be an error when used in a Module.

Comment: This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syxdc22(v=vs.90).aspx) on the MSDN lists keywords that cannot be used in a module.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Overloads" keyword in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173257/overloads-keyword-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not neccessary. You can overload methods and properties without the `Overloads` keyword.

However, if you use the `Overloads` or `Overrides` keyword on one overload of a method, you have to use it on all other overloads to that method in the class.

You can use the `Overloads` keyword instead of the `Shadows` keyword to shadow an inherited method with the same signature. Then you have to use either of the keywords, they are not both optional.

Comment: See [Shadows vs Overloads in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515037/shadows-vs-overloads-in-vb-net) for more information.

Comment: Hard to believe this hasn't been corrected after all these years. 'Overload' is not always optional - if another method of the same name in the same class overrides a base class method, then 'Overloads' is necessary.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Read the second paragraph.

Comment: @Guffa: See my answer - even if you don't choose to use 'Overloads' on any method, the compiler will force you to add it in some circumstances - not optional.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Yes, that's what it says in the second paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one case where the keyword `Overloads` is mandatory.  If a method has the keyword `Overloads` then any new method of the same name within the type must also have `Overloads`

Other than that case, the keyword is optional.

Answer (score 1):

you don’t have to use the Overloads keyword to specify an overloaded method while within the same class. This is how C# handles overloading – there is no Overloads keyword in C#.
But using the Overloads keyword, tends to be more readable.
Check out [this blog post](http://ninopriore.com/the-overloads-overrides-and-shadows-keywords-in-vb-net-part-2/) for more detailed information.

Comment: That blog post is now a dead link :-(

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of accuracy, I'm making this very late response since I noticed that the existing answers are simply incorrect. 'Overloads' is certainly required in a few cases, most commonly when another method of the same name overrides a base class method, as in the following example - the code simply will not compile if the 'Overloads' keyword is removed:

```
Public Class One
    Public Overridable Sub method()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Two
    Inherits One

    Public Overrides Sub method()
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub method(ByVal i As Integer)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The existing answers are not incorrect, you just haven't read them carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, there are times when you *can't* use the `Overloads` keyword. For example:

```
Module MyModule
    Overloads Sub MySub(Param1 As String)
    End Sub
    Overloads Sub MySub(Param1 As String, Param2 As Integer)
    End Sub
End Module
```

The compiler throws error, "Inappropriate use of 'Overloads' keyword in a module".

Not sure why, as you can still overload the method as usual.