# Why I must use Overloads here?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, overriding

First, please look at this custom Button-inherited UserControl code:

```
Public Class UserControl1

Dim _Text As String
Dim _Image As Image

<Browsable(True), Description("Gets or sets the text displayed on the button")> _
Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return _Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Text = value
        MyBase.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

<Browsable(True), Description("Gets or sets the image displayed on the button")> _
Overloads Property Image() As Image
    Get
        Return _Image
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Image)
        _Image = value
        'ReDrawMe()
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

That's ALL the code of the UserControl. The `Overrides` at `Text` property is OK, but I don't know why VS tell me I CAN'T use `Overrides` at `Image` property, but I can use `Overloads`. Why? I thought `Overloads` only use if there're multiple methods with the same name (different parameters). Two things I still doubt:

1. Why `Image` is the only property declaration in this class, but it must be called `Overloads`?
2. The `Property` doesn't have any parameter (of course), so how could `Overloads` possible?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the [`Image` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx) in the `ButtonBase` class isn’t declared as `Overridable` you cannot override it in derived classes.

You can *shadow* the parent declaration (i.e. hide it) by redeclaring it in the deriving class as `Shadows` or `Overloads`. The difference between these two is rather small (§1.15.3 in the VB language specification):

- **`Shadows`** shadows *by name*: if a method (or property) is declared `Shadows` then it shadows *all* base class methods (or properties) of the same name.
- **`Overloads`** shadows *by name and signature*: it only hides a method of the same name *and* same signature.

In your case, both result in the same because there is only a single property of that name.

Either way, if the parent property isn’t marked as overridable, then redefining it in a derived class is a bad idea – it won’t work properly when your control is accessed via its base class type.

Comment: If then, why can we use `Overloads`? Isn't it only use for methods? And how could the language distinguish the overloaded properties, since they don't have any unique parameters?

Comment: @W.N. You *can* overload properties in VB because properties in VB (not in C#!) can have arguments. Why it’s possible here, I don’t know.

Comment: @W.N. is a special "version" of a method that encapusulates a getter and or setter method.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I see your edited answer. But I don't understand about `Shadows` very much, and it make my inherited properties not work properly, so I always use overrides for my UserControls.

Comment: @Jodrell: maybe it's an acceptable answer, since we don't have a better understanding about it.

Comment: @W.N. Yes, `Shadows` is rarely (if ever) useful. In fact, I’ve never used it. But unfortunately the property simply cannot be overridden.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph In fact, using `Overloads` for `Image property` acts just like using `Overrides` for `Text property`, so it's not a really big problem. Just somehow, weird in concept. I only needed to know why this happens.

Comment: @W.N. I’ve looked it up in the VB spec and have found out why `Overloads` works here. See updated answer.

Comment: See [Shadows vs Overloads in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515037/shadows-vs-overloads-in-vb-net/4760614#4760614) for confirmation of @KonradRudolph's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no Overidable Image Property on UserControl. If you want to declare it with the same signature you would need to use the `Shadows` keyword, this could in turn be `Overridable` for the next inheritor.

EDIT:

Its an indication that the Author of button doesent think you should override image.

Comment: Really? I don't think overriding Image property cause problem, since we can even override OnPaint event.

Comment: @W.N. I'm not the author of `Button`. What is special about about your implementation of `Image`, why does the base `Image` not work?

Comment: lol, funny (but, yeah, you're right) answer. BTW, Thanks for your answer. +1 vote :) Happy coding.

Comment: There're something else I need to do when user set data for Image property, so I have to overrides it.