# CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 0 arguments?

Tags: c#, f#

How is it possible for no overload of ToString to take zero arguments? The zero-argument ToString is part of System.Object!

*Edit in response to the close vote:* **Since I'm not in a position to upgrade my build server to .NET 4.5, is there any way to make this code work with the .NET 4.0/VS 2010 compilers?** Short of giving my overload a completely different name, which is just not cool.

- The object in question is an F# Discriminated Union that overrides the ToString method inherited from System.Object.
- The overridden ToString is being called by code in a C# project that's part of the same solution.
- This all worked fine until I added an extra overload of ToString to my discriminated union, which takes one argument.
- It all builds and runs perfectly on my local machine (VS 2012, all projects targeting .NET 4.0)
- It fails on the build server (.NET 4.0) - the C# compiler error in the title showed up as soon as I added the 1-argument overload of ToString to my discriminated union.

I guess the simplest workaround would be to rename my ToString overload to something else, but this is bizarre.

Here's a simple reproduction. You can download a zip file of a solution containing this code here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1742470/CS1501_Repro.zip

Compiling that solution in VS 2010 will fail with "CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 0 arguments". Compiling it in VS 2012 will work just fine. In both cases we're targeting .NET Framework 4.

**F#**

```ml
namespace CS1501_Repro.FSharp

open System

[<Serializable>]
type MyDiscriminatedUnion =
    | Foo of int list
    | Bar of string
    | Baz of int
    | Fizz of float
    | Buzz of DateTimeOffset

    override this.ToString() =
        "Zero Arguments"

    member this.ToString(lookup:Func<int,string>) =
        "One Argument"
```

**C#**

```cs
using System;
using CS1501_Repro.FSharp;

namespace CS1501_Repro.CSharp
{
    public class Caller
    {
        private MyDiscriminatedUnion _item;

        public Caller(MyDiscriminatedUnion item)
        {
            _item = item;
        }

        public string DoThing()
        {
            return _item.ToString();
        }

        public string DoOtherThing()
        {
            return _item.ToString(i => i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code to reproduce the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this with a short but complete example (just a disriminated union in F#, and C# code calling it)?

Comment: Is it possible you called it `toString` or something like that (some subtly different name)?

Comment: I'll see if I can make an isolated reproduction - it'll take me a few minutes because I need to fix the broken build first and test my code on two machines to verify that I've reproduced it.

Comment: @Servy - Nope. I'm working around this issue by changing it to a subtly different name (ToLabelString).

Comment: I've updated with sample code reproducing the problem, and a link to download a solution zip that demonstrates it.

Comment: Interestingly, if you convert the F# project to Visual Studio 2012 and build it there, then the C# project is able to build successfully back in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a partial answer, but I noticed that VS2010 and VS2012 generate different IL for the F# class. If you look at the IL for the `ToString(lookup:Func<int,string>)` method, then you will see that the output in VS2010 is:

```
.method public instance string  ToString(class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,string> lookup) cil managed
{
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  3
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "One Argument"
  IL_0006:  ret
} // end of method MyDiscriminatedUnion::ToString
```

while the output in VS2012 is:

```
.method public hidebysig instance string 
        ToString(class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,string> lookup) cil managed
{
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "One Argument"
  IL_0006:  ret
} // end of method MyDiscriminatedUnion::ToString
```

The difference is the `hidebysig` annotation in the method signature. If `hidebysig` is added, then the method will hide other implementations (in the base class) that share the same name and signature, while if `hidebysig` is omitted, it will hide all other implementations with the same name even if the signature is different. [This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656325/what-is-the-purpose-of-hidebysig-in-a-msil-method) contains a good answer that describes `hidebysig`.

So while this answer doesn't solve your problem, it explains why it doesn't compile in VS2010.

Comment: Thanks for the information on `hidebysig` - it definitely sounds like that's the issue. I guess it's a work-around for me, at least until I get the go-ahead to update the compilers on the build server.

Answer (score 5):

I have to admit, this is the first time I have ever used F#, so this solution is probably not the most elegant, however, you mentioned that ToString() is part of System.Object...

I solved this issue by adding a line of code into the DoThing() method which assigns _item to object, and then calls ToString() from the object, giving, in this instance, the desired result:

**F# code (unchanged)**

```
type MyDiscriminatedUnion =
    | Foo of int list
    | Bar of string
    | Baz of int
    | Fizz of float
    | Buzz of DateTimeOffset

    override this.ToString() = "Zero Arguments"
    member this.ToString(lookup:Func<int,string>) = "One Argument"
```

**C# code (see change in DoThing() method)**

```
    public class Caller
    {
        private Module1.MyDiscriminatedUnion _item;

        public Caller(Module1.MyDiscriminatedUnion item)
        {
            _item = item;
        }

        public string DoThing()
        {
            object result = _item; //assign to object
            return result.ToString(); //call ToString() on object
        }

        public string DoOtherThing()
        {
            return _item.ToString(i => i.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I do apologize if this is not what you want...but it's all I can think of, and if anyone thinks it's the wrong way to go about it, please do say why!

Comment: That's a good thought, casting to object. As workarounds go, I think I prefer just giving my overload a different name than ToString, but there's certainly nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: Wouldn't a cast work just as well? `((object)_item).ToString()`